# In Chrome Devtools, how do I see which file a piece of css is in?

Tags: meteor

Right now all my *.css files and package css show up as a single 30k-line CSS file, and sometimes it's hard to tell which file/package line eg 20,241 belongs to. This is running `meteor` locally in development.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's not normal. Something must be combining all the CSS files into one big file. Are you using something like `LESS`? Is this something `Meteor` does?

Comment: @Barmar Meteor's build chain automatically concatenates CSS sources into one file to simplify how it automatically live reloads CSS changes into running applications. In production, it also minifies the CSS file.

Comment: it should be a index.html file with the css files on the head tag

Comment: @Ethaan that's not how Meteor loads CSS. JS files are kept as separate `<script>` tags for development and then aren't concatenated/minified until you run it under production. But CSS files in your application tree and any packages you rely on are concatenated even in development. This simplifies the live injection of CSS changes because Meteor only has to replace a single CSS `<link>` in the DOM.

Comment: @sbking upps i didn't know that, i never mess with my css files on my meteor apps (my friend does =p), thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks @sbking, so is it your understanding that currently there's no meteor setting or package that keeps the CSS files separated or provides Chrome a source map?

Comment: @Loren Meteor *does* provide a CSS source map to chrome. If you inspect an element and look at the styles defined for it, you'll see links to the individual CSS files and line numbers. However, I don't know how to see the sources when looking at the concatenated CSS file. Personally, I put a comment at the top of each of my application style files, and package styles will always come first in the stylesheet.

Comment: I don't see a CSS source map (see updated pictures in question). Chrome version 40. Any idea how I can diagnose why that is?